# PHP Repeat a func when variable doesn't meet requirement

Tags: php, mysql, loops, repeat

I'm newbie at PHP (I'm learning it) so could someone help me to fix my script?

```
$total = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files;"));
$rand = rand(0,$total);
$check = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE id=".$rand.";"));
do {
$rand;
}
while($check < 1);
```

I write this code to get a random column ID from MySQL ( I tried "ORDER BY RAND()" but it's too slow), When this ID doesnt exist in MySQL's table it will repeat this job until it find a exist ID with this way:

```
$check = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE id=".$rand.";"));
```

But I think I was wrong in coding it. Please help me to fix. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, he could simply use ```SELECT MAX(id) FROM files;``` as his initial query. I'll update my answer accordingly

Comment: @Yoshi Then ```$check``` will be 0 and the loop will continue.

Comment: Yes, Yoshi.
Use RAND() or something like that with MySQL isn't good because of CPU problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to place the query inside the loop otherwise it won't actually check again. See below:

```
$total = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM files;"));
$check = 0;
do {
$rand = rand(0,$total);
$check = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE id=".$rand.";"));
}
while($check < 1);
```

Comment: You may want to use `mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM files;"), 0, 0);` since `num_rows` will always return 1 in the given instance, and that doesn't tell you much. Still, this answer is better than calling num_rows after fetching every row from the database.

Comment: I'd also recommend storing the resultset in a var, rather than discarding it after each loop, to avoid the extra query later on when you want to use that record.

Comment: I dont think should use **SELECT MAX(id) FROM files** because it will return **6** when ID list is 1,4,5,6. @Psychemaster

Comment: @DavidMcintyre Yes, and then if the random number lands somewhere without an associated ID (say 3) then ```$check``` will be 0 and the loop will continue. I mentioned this in the question comments above.

Answer (score 0):

Is it ok?

```
do {
$rand = rand(0,$total);
}
while(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE id=".$rand.";")) < 1);
```